# In how many bit strings of length 10 are there with no 3 0s adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-combinatorics

it is hard for me dealing with more than 2 not adjacency problems, I need some straightforward approaches for these kinda problems, I have searched most of the community looking for similar problems but I got sorta more confused.
 it would be very nice of you to put me in the right direction. The title is my question A
But for B:
B)if at least 3 0s are not adjacent?

A) My notion is, 2 0's are allowed,
So at first as we got only 3 0s to place in,  I get the total by $10\choose3$ =$120$
And for 3 adjacent 0s: 
0001111111,1000111111,1100011111,1110001111,1111000111,1111100011,1111110001,1111111000, indicating we have only 8 locations to place our consecutive 0s, subtracting this from the total , $120 - 8 = 112$ , was this a correct approach?

For B)  it means we can place in more 0s than just 3 right? If so , non consequtive 3 0s,4 0s, ... , 10 0s 
Summing them all up we have 36, hence 120 - 36 = 84 .  ?
Help please..

Comment: Are you familiar with Markov chains and probability transition matrices?

Comment: @hardmath not yet unfortunately! I need to stick to combination rules with these kinda stuffs

Comment: If I understand (B), it doesn't seem to relate to (A) very much.  You could have three zeros that are not adjacent, and despite this you might or might not have three zeros that are adjacent (e.g. all ten bits zeros or alternating bits zero and one).

Comment: @hardmath so what is your opinion ? About A ? Was that one correct ?

Comment: Is for A given that the number of 0's is exactly three? Then it is correct.

Comment: Do you know the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: For A) you should consider cases to form a recurrence relation. You should get the tribonacci numbers.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes .

Comment: @Nicholas so u mean I cant stay on combinatorics on that one ? And it's totally incorrect ? Why .. it really seems to be answer :( what about exactly 3 0s ? Thanks for the replies

Comment: @Pieter21 I think it is, what about second one ? Thanks

Comment: What about $0001000011$? Would it be counted for A? And how to properly include/exclude with inclusion/exclusion?

Comment: @Pieter21 what if it is like that way, I mean if more than 3 is allowed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For all who might come across my problem and would like to know about the combinatorial solution:

1. We start with 10 1s and 0 0.
   $10\choose0$ = 0
2. 9 1's, means we got 10 gaps to place one 0,
   $10\choose1$ = 10
3. 8 1's,  we got 9 gaps left and we should choose 2 locations to place 0, $or$ choose one single location to place $00$
   $9\choose2$ + $9\choose1 $
4. 7 1's,  we got 8 gaps left and we should choose 3 locations to place 0, $or$ choose 2 locations to place 00 and 0, with $\frac{2!}{1!}$ ways for their arrangement.
   $8\choose3$ + $8\choose2 $ $\times$ $\frac{2!}{1!}$
5. The string includes 6 1's, leaving us with 7 gaps in between, either we should choose 4 locations to place 0, $or$ choose 3 locations to place 00 and 0,0 with $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways for their arrangement.. $or$ 2 locations to place 00,00 
   $7\choose4$ + $7\choose3 $ $\times$ $\frac{3!}{3-1!}$ + $7\choose2$
6. The string includes 5 1's, leaving us with 6 gaps in between, either we should choose 5 locations to fill with 0's, $or$ choose 4 locations to place 00 and 0, 0, 0 with $\frac{4!}{3!}$ ways for their arrangement.. $or$ 3 locations to place 00,00 ,0
   $6\choose5$ + $6\choose4 $ $\times$ $\frac{4!}{4-1!}$ + $6\choose3$ $\times$ $\frac{3}{3-1}$
7. The string includes 4 1's, leaving us with 5 gaps in between, either we should choose 5 locations to place 00,0,0,0,0 with $\frac{5!}{4!}$ ways for their arrangement $or$ choose 4 locations to place 00 and 00, 0, 0 with $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$ ways to arrange them. $or$ we can choose 3 locations to place 00,00 ,00 
   $5\choose5$ $\times$ $\frac{5!}{5-1!}$ + $5\choose4 $ $\times$ $\frac{4!}{4-2!4-2!}$ + $5\choose3$
8. The string includes 3 1's, leaving us with 4 gaps
   we should choose 4 locations to place 00,00,00,0 with $\frac{4!}{3!1!}$ ways for their arrangement 
   $4\choose4$ $\times$ $\frac{4!}{3!1!}$

Summing them all up, we get 504...

Comment: 1. should be 1. You need some ()'s in e.g. (4-1)! Apart from that, you don't want to extend this solution to length >= 15.

Answer (score 3):

if the question is "How many bitstrings of length 10 exist with three 0's, but non-adjacent?" Your solution to A. of 112 is right.

For B, you'd have to write a recurrence relation.

You can compose any acceptable string by combining $1, 01, 001$.
The number of words you can create like this satisfies $w_n = w_{n-1} + w_{n-2} + w_{n-3}$. Since you can also finish with 0, 1, or 2 trailing 0's, you are interested in $w_8 +w_9 + w_{10}$ which happens to be $w_{11}$.

You have the tribonacci numbers, with an offset, so I think the answer is 504.
http://oeis.org/A000073

Comment: Thank you very much, I can understand your solution, so the only way is to use recurrences for these kinda problems?

Comment: @Pieter21 Your index is off by one; the answer is 504.

Comment: True.. Correct answer 504