# How many bitstrings of length n are there with c adjacent 1s somewhere?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, kolmogorov-complexity

I am self-studying Kolmogorov complexity, and for its purposes, (Sipser exercise 6.26) I am trying to prove that for constant c, as n approaches infinity, the ratio of bitstrings of length n that contain $(1)^{c}$, to the ratio of bitstrings of length n approaches 1. (More than c consecutive 1s are acceptable as well, and not all 1s of the string need to be consecutive.) It's hard to do without counting good strings more than once.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1530139 Seems to answer the question for specific n and c, but it doesn't seem easy to calculate as n tends to infinity and for general c.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: One (possible) approach, that may not be practical: Let $f(n)$ denote the number of $n$ length bit strings that do **not** have $c$ consecutive $1$'s.  You would need to show that there exists $r < 2$, such that for all $n \geq ~(\text{some}) ~N, ~\dfrac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} < r.$ ...see next comment

Comment: A similar approach, [with $~f(n)~$ defined as the corresponding reciprocal] was taken in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605103/how-many-coin-flips-would-it-take-to-have-a-90-chance-of-flipping-3-heads-in-a/4605189#4605189).  However, that answer, which used recursion, had the great advantage of a fixed small number for $c$, namely $c=3.$  I suspect that using recursion on the (generic) variable $c$ would require a deep knowledge of Markov Chains, of which I am totally ignorant.

Comment: I bet the rate of growth of this is the eigenvalue of some relevant matrix. EDIT: This is probably on the order of $\rho^n$ where $\rho$ is the root of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a probabilistic way. Fix $c \geq 1$ and consider $n$ large enough. Consider choosing a bitstring $\mathbf{x}$ of length $n$ uniformly at random; or equivalently, each bit $x_i$ is independently $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$. Now the aim is to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{x} \not\ni (1)^c) = o(1) \quad(*)
$$
(where the notation on the left-handside means the random bitstring contains a sequence of $c$ consecutive $1$'s somewhere). If we show this, then this implies that $\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{x} \ni (1)^c) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, or equivalently that the ratio of bitstrings with the desired property to all bitstrings tends to one.

To show $(*)$: Consider chopping up the $n$ bits into $n / c$ consecutive blocks of $c$ bits (we will assume that $n/c \in \mathbb{Z}$ for simplicity, but the general argument only requires an easy modification). Then if the event on the left-hand side happens, it must be that each of these $n/c$ blocks must all be different from a sequence of $c$ 1's. For each block, this happens with probability $1 - 2^{-c}$. Thus, by independence, we have that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{x} \not\ni (1)^c) \leq (1 - 2^{-c})^{n/c}.
$$
Since $c$ is fixed, it follows that the upper bound tends to 0 as $n \to \infty$.